# d3.csv over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, csv, https, d3.js

I know that `d3.csv` makes an HTTP get request. But what if my file is stored in a place with HTTPS protocol? I can store all my files(the .js, the data and the .html that holds everything together) in the same directory but they are all accessed via HTTPS.

Unfortunately I have no option to go http because this is for a work application on the company intranet.

Comment: Did you face any particular problems in communicating over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript app is (largely) protocol agnostic and it doesn't matter to the program whether the protocol is HTTP or HTTPS. Those details will be handled by the browser and as long as certificates do not present a problem, the user is not likely to notice either.

If all your files are saved on the same server within the same root folder, you *should make* requests *relative* to your own path, e.g. `d3.csv('./data.csv')`, and it should work just fine. Only if your are making cross domain requests does protocol become important.